# Jupyter Notebook file seems to be saved as an html instead of a .IPYNB

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was browsing for the question in the title and none of the proposed answers worked for me. I saved three Jupyter notebooks with all my notes on a topic, and now they seem to be html files. I saved them using Save Notebook As... in Jupyter, so if anyone can tell me if this is right, that would be much appreciated.

The problem I have now is that I need my notes (both markdown and code) to check some details and I don't seem to be able to open the file as a notebook, only as a plain text html file.

Is there any way to get it back to a .IPYNB file? None of the options that I could find worked for me. I tried running this code, but had no success:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import urllib.request
#url = 'http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/jakevdp.github.com/downloads/notebooks/XKCD_plots.ipynb'
#response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
#  for local html file
response = open("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/MICHEL/DATA SCIENCE/WEB SCRAPING (UDEMY)/WEB SCRAPING PAGINA ESTATICA/LXML/web_scraping_con_lxml")
text = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
# see some of the html
print(soup.div)
dictionary = {'nbformat': 4, 'nbformat_minor': 1, 'cells': [], 'metadata': {}}
for d in soup.findAll("div"):
    if 'class' in d.attrs.keys():
        for clas in d.attrs["class"]:
            if clas in ["text_cell_render", "input_area"]:
                # code cell
                if clas == "input_area":
                    cell = {}
                    cell['metadata'] = {}
                    cell['outputs'] = []
                    cell['source'] = [d.get_text()]
                    cell['execution_count'] = None
                    cell['cell_type'] = 'code'
                    dictionary['cells'].append(cell)

                else:
                    cell = {}
                    cell['metadata'] = {}

                    cell['source'] = [d.decode_contents()]
                    cell['cell_type'] = 'markdown'
                    dictionary['cells'].append(cell)
open('notebook.ipynb', 'w').write(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

The file is in the location that you can see in the program. Does anyone know how can I fix this and how can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: That's a good question! I think that some details may help though. You say you tried other answers to other questions, but do not link them. How can we know that the solution we propose is not something you already tried? Please be more specific. Also, you say that you had no success with the code cited above. What exactly do you mean? Was there an error? Did it produce incorrect notebook? Finally, can you provide an example html file (possibly with most cells redacted, but one markdown and one code cell left) just to demonstrate the format you have)?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad. I just asked a professor and he showed me that my computer was saving the code in a different format from .ipynb . I simply switched the file extension manually to .ipynb to solve the problem. Now I can open the files again with the notebook and get the regular format.

Thanks!